Wavesurfer JS - How to give Style to Shadow DOM custom class?
I am already following
https://wavesurfer.xyz/examples/?styling.js
It's part of Shadow DOM.

Class regionHighlight if available then only we want to apply the class. There are multiple regions within waveform
HTML is <div id="waveform"></div>
So CSS will be like
#waveform {
  ::part(region) {

   &.is(.regionHighlight) {
    border: 2px solid red;
   }
  }
}

Above code is not working somehow. I am only able to give CSS via part only.

Because part="region" does exactly that; it allows you to access/style that one HTML node. Think of it this way; I give you the keys to my mailbox, and that will not get you into my house.
